# Does Windows Phone support MSMQ?

Tags: c#, msmq

I need to write an app where Windows Phone mobile sends and listen messages from a queue placed in a Windows 2012 server. I am thinking several options:  creating a queue manually using SQL Server + web services, or RabbitMQ or MSMQ.

Is MSMQ supported by Windows Phone? Reading the documentation I am not sure.

Comment: MSMQ is listed in MSDN as a desktop technology, and doesn't show any reference to windows phone 8 or Silverlight, so I think it's unlikely.

Comment: No, it is not. this is a SERVER based technology. why on earth would you want a phone to listen and send messages over a queue? instead, why not maybe use Azure mobile notification services? perhaps couple it with Servicebus?

Comment: Ahmed, from the Phone, I send an image to the server. When the image is processed, the server would notify to the mobile that the job is done. Of course, the queues reside in the server.

Comment: Normally the phone would connect via a web service conduit. WCF supports both web services (obviously) and MSMQ.

Comment: Yes, but I need that the phone receives a notification from the server, and it is not possible with web services. I was looking for a subscriber service.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ is not exposed over the Internet, so no, you cannot.

Comment: Really? You can send MSMQ messages to a website over HTTP and HTTPS. The tricky part is writing a queue manager on Windows Phone to handle the message flow.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell MSMQ-over-HTTP isn't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No MSMQ on Windows Phone AFAIK.

[Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/msmq-on-windows-phone-very-unlikely.aspx)